# variable with "true" value does not meet [variable] == "true" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable declared as true

```
var g1 = sessionStorage.getItem("g1"); //true
var g2 = sessionStorage.getItem("g2"); //false
var g3 = sessionStorage.getItem("g3"); //false
```

but in my function

```
function checkmonitogift() {
    console.log(g1);
    if (g1 == true) {
        $("#g1").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(176,5,8,.9)",
            "cursor": "not-allowed"
        });
        $("#g1").html("OK");
    }

    if (g2 == false) {
        $("#g2").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(176,5,8,.9)",
            "cursor": "not-allowed"
        });
        $("#g2").html("OK");
    }

    if (g3 == false) {
        $("#g3").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(176,5,8,.9)",
            "cursor": "not-allowed"
        });
        $("#g3").html("OK");
    }

}
```

console return "true" but it still does not meet the condition of the `if` statement

Comment: use `var g1 = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem("g1"))`

Comment: `"true" == true` is the same as `NaN == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var g1 = sessionStorage.getItem("g1");

here the output type is string so you can not check like this

```
if (g1 == true) {
```

chage your code to

```
if (g1 == "true") {
```

or if you feel you are getting boolean value then do this

```
if (g1) {
 or
if (!g1) {
```

Comment: *"or if you feel you are getting boolean value"* But they are not. `g1` is a string as you said.

Comment: definitely, g1 is a string but I just gave the option to check boolean values in if() condition

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage.getItem("g2")` returns `"true"` (string) instead of `true` (boolean)

Make it

```
var g1 = sessionStorage.getItem("g1") == "true" ; //true
var g2 = sessionStorage.getItem("g2") == "true"; //false
var g3 = sessionStorage.getItem("g3") == "true"; //false
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can do to compare `string` to `boolean`

The two I would prefer are :

```
var trueStr = "true";
var g1 = (trueStr === sessionStorage.getItem("g1") ); 
var g2 = (trueStr === sessionStorage.getItem("g2") ); 
var g3 = (trueStr ===  sessionStorage.getItem("g3") );
```

or

```
var g1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("g1")); 
var g2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("g2")); 
var g3 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("g3"));
```

Then your variables will be `boolean`adn rest will work fine.